# Don't know how to prove this inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Suppose $x >0, y \in (0,1),  y(1+x) \in (0, 1)$, how can I prove that

$$(x+y) [\ln (x+y) - \ln y]
+(1-x-y) [\ln (1-x-y) - \ln (1-y)]
\geq
y [x - (1+x) \ln (1+x)]?$$

I have no clue about how to start. It is a part that will help solving another problem. $y$ and $y(1+x)$ can be thought as the parameters of two Bernoulli distributions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you put your original problem here and regard this question as part of your thought since you put a tag `probability` to your question.

Comment: Thanks! The question is motivated under probability background. However, the question itself is purely real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you want to prove is equivalent to:
$$\frac{1}{y}[(x+y) [\ln (x+y) - \ln y]
+(1-x-y) [\ln (1-x-y) - \ln (1-y)]]
\geq
x - (1+x) \ln (1+x)?$$

So why not studying $\varphi_x(y) = \frac{1}{y}[(x+y) [\ln (x+y) - \ln y] +(1-x-y) [\ln (1-x-y) - \ln (1-y)]]$

and minimizing it on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Thx! You meant minimizing it?

Comment: @steveO yes! Just edited the answer accordingly. I am too lazy to study the function myself but that shouldn't be so hard...